# Disable swipe gesture when using BottomNavigationBar

Tags: dart, flutter

How do we disable swipe on BottomNavigationBar attached to a scaffold?

I could not find a way in the official docs to do so.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you included the code you're working with, or even better, a minimal, complete, and verifiable code excerpt to reproduce your problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it:

Just use

```
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

on your scrollable widget!