# How allow vertical scroll and disable horizontal swipe with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've the following page:

[image]

With a bottombar and three pages.
I want to enable vertical scrolling, but disable the swipe.

I used the suggestion [physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688819/disable-swipe-gesture-when-using-bottomnavigationbar/51688884#51688884) in a SingleChildScrollView, but then the vertical scrolling is disabled, but I still can swipe.

A part of my code:

```
...
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      controller: ScrollController(),
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('AAA'),
            Text('AAA'),
            Text('AAA'),
            Text('AAA'),
...
```

I build the 'tabs' with PageViews:

```
  Widget buildPageView() {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        Page1Screen(),
        Page2Screen(),
        Page3Screen(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: What are you using for horizontal pages, `PageView`???

Comment: @HemanthRaj; Yes! I added the code which makes the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply add `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to - `PageView`

```
PageView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // add this
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
           pageChanged(index);
        },
        children: <Widget>[
          Page1Screen(),
          Page2Screen(),
          Page3Screen(),
        ],
      ),
```